# Expander direction error InvalidOperationException: Header not initialized

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, expander, xamarin-community-toolkit

When set `Expander` direction an error message is displayed

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Header not initialized'

```
<xct:Expander Direction="Left">
    <xct:Expander.Header>
        <Label Text="H" TextColor="Black"/>
    </xct:Expander.Header>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Label Text="!" TextColor="Black" />
        <Label Text="D" TextColor="Red" />
    </StackLayout>
</xct:Expander>
```

The code works fine if there is no direction attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/1144 which has been fixed [in this pr](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/pull/1147) and will be available on a next release.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the direction after the header definition made it works for me.

```
<xct:Expander>
    <xct:Expander.Header>
        <Label Text="H" TextColor="Black"/>
    </xct:Expander.Header>
    <xct:Expander.Direction>
        <xct:ExpandDirection>Left</xct:ExpandDirection>
    </xct:Expander.Direction>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Label Text="!" TextColor="Black" />
        <Label Text="D" TextColor="Red" />
    </StackLayout>
</xct:Expander>
```